# How to inject spring bean into ContainerRequestFilter using AutoWired?

Tags: java, spring, filter, resteasy

I'm using `RESTEasy 3` and `Spring 4` and I'm trying to inject `@Autowired` an service bean into my interceptor as follow below:

But running this code it's returning `Null Pointer Exception` when access my access service:

```
@Provider
@MyAnnotationToIntercept
public class MyInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {


    private MyAccessService accessService;

    @Autowired
    public MyInterceptor(MyAccessService accessService) {
        this.accessService = accessService;
    }

    public MyInterceptor() {
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        // DO SOME STUFF Using accessService
    }
}


@Component
public class MyAccessService {

    private MyDep1 dep1;

    @Autowired
    public MyAccessService(Mydep1 dep1) {
        this.dep1= dep1;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? It's really possible?

Comment: @SumeshTG it's not a method it's a Constructor

Comment: @Autowired   private MyAccessService accessService;   Try this.

Comment: @SumeshTG same Null Pointer error

Comment: Is your component scan configuration is correct?

Comment: @SumeshTG yes for other dependencies.. i'll try to check for this package

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `WebApplicationContextUtils`'s method to get a bean inside filter which is not managed by spring. Here is the example

```
MyAccessService myAccessService = (MyAccessService) WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(httpServletRequest .getServletContext()).getBean(MyAccessService.class);
```

And to get `HttpServletRequest` instance you can use `@context` injection

```
  @Context
  private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have placed @Autowired annotation at the wrong place. It should be above the declaration of accessService. And depending on how you have configured application context, you may/may not need a setter method for accessService instance variable.